# Multiple assignment in Scala without using Array?

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, variable-assignment

I have an input something like this: `"1 2 3 4 5"`.

What I would like to do, is to create a set of new variables, let `a` be the first one of the sequence, `b` the second, and `xs` the rest as a sequence (obviously I can do it in 3 different lines, but I would like to use multiple assignment).

A bit of search helped me by finding the [right-ignoring sequence patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/122), which I was able to use:

```
val Array(a, b, xs @ _*) = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ")
```

What I do not understand is that why doesn't it work if I try it with a tuple? I get an error for this:

```
val (a, b, xs @ _*) = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ")
```

The error message is:

```
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple pattern
```

Are there any alternatives for multiple-assignment without using `Array`?

I have just started playing with Scala a few days ago, so please bear with me :-) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Other answers tell you why you can't use tuples, but arrays are awkward for this purpose.  I prefer lists:

```
val a :: b :: xs = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ").toList
```

Comment: That is more clean

Answer (score 12):

### Simple answer

```
val Array(a, b, xs @ _*) = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ")
```

The syntax you are seeing here is a simple pattern-match.  It works because `"1 2 3 4 5".split(" ")` evaluates to an `Array`:

```
scala> "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ")
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Since the right-hand-side is an `Array`, the pattern on the left-hand-size must, also, be an `Array`

The left-hand-side can be a tuple only if the right-hand-size evaluates to a tuple as well:

```
val (a, b, xs) = (1, 2, Seq(3,4,5))
```

---

### More complex answer

Technically what's happening here is that the pattern match syntax is invoking the `unapply` method on the `Array` object, which looks like this:

```
def unapplySeq[T](x: Array[T]): Option[IndexedSeq[T]] =
  if (x == null) None else Some(x.toIndexedSeq)
```

Note that the method accepts an `Array`.  This is what Scala must see on the right-hand-size of the assignment.  And it returns a `Seq`, which allows for the `@_*` syntax you used.

Your version with the tuple doesn't work because `Tuple3`'s `unapplySeq` is defined with a `Product3` as its parameter, not an `Array`:

```
def unapply[T1, T2, T3](x: Product3[T1, T2, T3]): Option[Product3[T1, T2, T3]] =
  Some(x)
```

You can actually "extractors" like this that do whatever you want by simply creating an object and writing an `unapply` or `unapplySeq` method.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is:

```
val a :: b :: c = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ").toList
```

Should clarify that in some cases one may want to bind just the first n elements in a list, ignoring the non-matched elements. To do that, just add a trailing underscore:

```
val a :: b :: c :: _ = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ").toList
```

That way:

```
c = "3" vs. c = List("3","4","5")
```

Comment: I posted apparently seconds after @Rex. Well, nice to know I had the same thought as a Scala "heavy" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in Scala by any means, but I think this might have to do with the fact that Tuples in Scala are just syntatic sugar for classes ranging from Tuple2 to Tuple22.

Meaning, Tuples in Scala aren't flexible structures like in Python or other languages of the sort, so it can't really create a Tuple with an unknown *a priori* size.

Comment: Ahh, now you mention it I can also recall that I read about that (I recall `Tuple22`, but the point is the same, it is strictly limited).

Answer (score 2):

We can use pattern matching to extract the values from string and assign it to multiple variables. This requires two lines though.

Pattern says that there are 3 numbers([0-9]) with space in between. After the 3rd number, there can be text or not, which we don't care about (.*).

```
val pat = "([0-9]) ([0-9]) ([0-9]).*".r
val (a,b,c) = "1 2 3 4 5" match { case pat(a,b,c) => (a,b,c) }
```

Output

```
a: String = 1
b: String = 2
c: String = 3
```